# Borrado con checkbox de un Listado paginado PHP BBDD

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

tengo un listado paginado de una tabla de la base de datos, lo que quiero hacer es que con checkbox se selecciones todos los que se quieran borrar. El problema está en que como el listado paginado no esta en un formulario luego al comprobar el checkbox es como que no lo envia.

Esto es el codigo del listado paginado que sale bien y ahi es donde añado una columna BORRAR que son los checkbox:

```
<?php
```

echo "";

```
                echo "<tr><th>CÓDIGO</th><th>BORRAR</th><th>NOMBRE</th><th>TELEFONO</th><th>EMAIL</th><th>FechaNac</th></tr>";
                foreach($bloqueRegistros as $row)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["CODIGO"]."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='alumnos[]' value='".$row['MAIL']."'></td><td>".$row["NOMBRE"]."</td><td>"
                               .$row["TELEFONO"]."</td><td>".$row["MAIL"]."</td><td>"
                               .$row["FechaNac"]."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<br><br>";
                
                dibujarBarraPaginacion($numPagina, $totalPaginas);
                echo "<br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Borrar'>";
            }else{
                echo "No hay registros";
            }
            echo "<br><hr><br>";
            
?>
```

Y aqui lo que tengo para borrar que lo tengo despues del body(cosa que no se si afecta en algo):

```
<?php

if(count($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $conn = conectaBD();
    foreach ($_POST['alumnos'] as $valor)
    {
        
        $sql = "DELETE FROM ALUMNOS WHERE MAIL= $valor";
        
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}else{
    echo "No se ha seleccionado ningun alumno";
}
?>
```

Comment: _"El problema está en que como el listado paginado no esta en un formulario luego al comprobar el checkbox es como que no lo envia"_. ¡Exacto, encontraste el problema!, debes usar un formulario.

Comment: Tal como te indica @Triby antes de la tabla debes escribir `echo '<form method="post">';` y despues de cerrarla `echo '</form>';`

Comment: si ya hice algo asi, muchas gracias.